# .NET C# Convert UTF-8/base64 string to image

Tags: c#, .net, string, utf-8, base64

I try to output a base64 string to an image and got it to work with a workaround that is actually - let's say - not very elegant.

I'm receiving a TCP stream from the server and encode it to UTF-8. The data contains a base64/png string. After I received it, I'm going to clean up the received message by deleting the server reply header and the linefeeds. Now I'm going to convert the string to bytes so I can send it to a temporary MemoryStream, which is used to generate the image in the last step.

The code for it looks like the following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Request the image from server
        Networker.send("THUMBNAIL RETRIEVE AMB\r\n");

        //Receive the reply from server in UTF-8 and store in string
        string received = Networker.receive();

        //clean the string by removing not needed information
        string cleanreceived = received.Replace("201 THUMBNAIL RETRIEVE OK\r\n", "");
        cleanreceived = cleanreceived.Replace("\n", "");
        cleanreceived = cleanreceived.Replace("\r", "");

        //convert string to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cleanreceived);

        // Convert byte[] to image and display in a pictureBox
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
        }

    }
```

However, this gives me the failure, that the input of the Convert.FromBase64String is a not valid Base64 string-sequence. I just thought, that the problem is, that I encoded the stream to UTF-8, but then I tried the following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Request the image from server
        Networker.send("THUMBNAIL RETRIEVE AMB\r\n");

        //Receive the reply from server in UTF-8 and store in string
        string received = Networker.receive();

        //clean the string by removing not needed information
        string cleanreceived = received.Replace("201 THUMBNAIL RETRIEVE OK\r\n", "");
        cleanreceived = cleanreceived.Replace("\n", "");
        cleanreceived = cleanreceived.Replace("\r", "");

        //store the clean text in a richTextBox
        richTextBox1.Text = cleanreceived;

        //store the text of the richTextBox in a new string
        string base64 = richTextBox1.Text;

        //convert string to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        // Convert byte[] to image and display in a pictureBox
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, false);
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
        }

    }
```

And.. it worked. So what I did is I send the string to a textbox from where it is called back into a new string. With that string I can convert from Base64 to bytes and so on.

However, is there a way to get the job more easy and elegant done, without the need of that textbox?

Thanks in advance and kind regards, Tobias

Comment: How does the string change when you put it in the textbox and take it back? Without any input data it's impossible for others to say anything. This isn't any common case, it's some custom system that outputs something.

Comment: That's the point. It doesn't change at all. I copied the cleanreceived string by command to the clipboard and compared it to the text of the textbox. There is absolutely no difference.

Comment: And when comparing the actual data, not something output by the textbox? Since they can't be exactly the same if it fixes something.

Comment: Can you give me a quick tip how to do that?

Comment: It would be useful to know if the length of the `imageBytes` array is the same both ways.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that helps me further. I now know that in the actual string are a lot of zeros at the end. Is there a way to get rid of those without touching the TCP Output? I think, I will do that later but for now...

Comment: Eh I removed my comment about the equality check for string because I don't know enough about strings and "culture insensitive" comparisons which I think is what `==` uses for equality checks.. maybe you want to compare with [`string.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx), which you should do after the `richTextBox1.Text = cleanreceived` line. In case it's not clear, it seems that the setter for `richTextBox1.Text` is modifying your string somehow, so after the assignment a `string.Compare(richTextBox1.Text, cleanreceived)` should give clues.

Comment: Got it! Fixed the TCP Client by checking the received byte array to the last 1 and resizing it to that point. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Sounds to me like the server is sending extraneous data. If you have control of the sender, you probably should fix it.